# Erro em instanceof em foreach

Tags: php, php-7

Tenho a seguinte **função**:

```
public function instanciaClasseArray ( $classe, $array ) : bool {

    foreach ($array as $objeto) : 

       if ( !($objeto instanceof $classe) ) return false;

    endforeach;

    return true;

}
```

E a seguinte **array** de **objetos**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos Object
        (
            [idEnderecos:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 144
            [idFonte:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 50
            [fonte:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => clientes
            [cep:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 36881038
            [tipo:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Rua
            [endereco:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Rua Francisco José Bane
            [numero:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => s/n
            [complemento:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Lote 06
            [bairro:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => São Francisco
            [cidade:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 36000
            [estado:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => MG
            [referencia:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Ao lado das rádios 98 e 102
        )

    [1] => classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos Object
        (
            [idEnderecos:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 165
            [idFonte:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 50
            [fonte:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => clientes
            [cep:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 36881038
            [tipo:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Rua
            [endereco:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Francisco José Bane
            [numero:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => s/n
            [complemento:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Lote 06
            [bairro:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => São Francisco
            [cidade:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 36000
            [estado:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => MG
            [referencia:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Ao lado das rádios 98 e 102
        )

    [2] => classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos Object
        (
            [idEnderecos:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 166
            [idFonte:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 50
            [fonte:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => clientes
            [cep:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 36881038
            [tipo:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Rua
            [endereco:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Francisco José Bane
            [numero:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => s/n
            [complemento:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Lote 06
            [bairro:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => São Francisco
            [cidade:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 36000
            [estado:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => MG
            [referencia:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Ao lado das rádios 98 e 102
        )

    [3] => classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos Object
        (
            [idEnderecos:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 168
            [idFonte:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 50
            [fonte:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => clientes
            [cep:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 36881038
            [tipo:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Rua
            [endereco:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Francisco José Bane
            [numero:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => s/n
            [complemento:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Lote 06
            [bairro:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => São Francisco
            [cidade:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 36000
            [estado:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => MG
            [referencia:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Ao lado das rádios 98 e 102
        )

    [4] => classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos Object
        (
            [idEnderecos:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 169
            [idFonte:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 50
            [fonte:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => clientes
            [cep:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 36881038
            [tipo:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Rua
            [endereco:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Rua Francisco José Bane
            [numero:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => s/n
            [complemento:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Lote 06
            [bairro:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => São Francisco
            [cidade:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => 36000
            [estado:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => MG
            [referencia:classes\mvc\modelos\EnderecosModelos:private] => Ao lado das rádios 102 e 98
        )

)
```

Estou fazendo da seguinte **forma**:

```
print_r (instanciaClasseArray ('EnderecosModelos', $array) );
```

O resultado está vindo **false**.

Onde está o **erro**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro ocorre pois o nome da classe está sendo passada como string. O certo seria você importar a classe dentro desse seu código e utilizá-la da seguinte forma:

```
print_r (instanciaClasseArray (EnderecosModelos::class, $array) );
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Era isso mesmo!